# ¿como cambiar de color al icono del menu css?

Tags: html, css

cómo podría cambiar el color del icono del menú que se me quedó blanco al cambiar de fondo el nav, ahora no le puedo dar color [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
```

Lo quisiera hacer con css. Gracias

Comment: Hola! podes agregar tu CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade la clase black-toggler a tu botón, y añade esto a tu css.
Y si acaso quisieras cambiar el color, sólo tienes que cambiar el color del borde en la clase navbar-toggler, y cambiar el rgb del stroke del svg en la background-image de navbar-toggler-icon. Espero te haya servido

```css
.black-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(0,0,0, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.black-toggler.navbar-toggler {
  border-color: #000;
}
```